# PHP/MySQL custom unique reference

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building an application which will allow different work teams to post on however; I need to have a unique reference for each post depending on which team they are on so the logic behind that is as follows

Team 1 - all posts will have an ID such as [will increment with each post 2, 3 etc]

```
CMPLX001
```

Team 2 - all posts will have an ID such as [will increment with each post 2, 3 etc]

```
GNRLS001
```

My issue is how I can increment each one as each of the teams need to start at 1 and then increment

Which is the best way to manage the id's when inserting new entries into the database?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: seperate tables will give the results desired if you want all of them to start at 1 and count. If on one table, id being primary key, they cannot have the same id num.

Comment: Sounds more like you want a foreign-key reference for the _team_ in each _post_, eg (in `post`) ~ `FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team (id)`. Don't encode relational data into identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a trigger on insert. I've created a simplified version of your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('CMPLX'), ('GNRLS');

CREATE TABLE posts (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    team_id INT,
                    team_post_id INT,
                    notes VARCHAR(100));

ALTER TABLE posts ADD FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id);

CREATE TRIGGER  update_tpid
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.team_post_id = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(team_post_id), 0) + 1
                          FROM posts 
                          WHERE team_id=NEW.team_id);


INSERT INTO posts (team_id, notes) VALUES
(1, 'team 1 first post'),
(2, 'team 2 first post'),
(1, 'team 1 second post'),
(1, 'team 1 third post'),
(2, 'team 2 second post'),
(1, 'team 1 fourth post'),
(2, 'team 2 third post'),
(1, 'team 1 fifth post');

SELECT concat(t.name, lpad(p.team_post_id, 3, '0')) AS post_id, p.notes 
FROM `posts` p
JOIN teams t ON t.id = p.team_id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Output:

```
post_id     notes   
CMPLX001    team 1 first post
GNRLS001    team 2 first post
CMPLX002    team 1 second post
CMPLX003    team 1 third post
GNRLS002    team 2 second post
CMPLX004    team 1 fourth post
GNRLS003    team 2 third post
CMPLX005    team 1 fifth post
```